# How to view the javascript code in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

When I go to others' page, I want to see the Javascript code how others write.

Can I view the js code by right click and inspect (chrome) , I know html and css can be seen, but how about js code?

Comment: Yes, it can be seen there.

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools)  is always useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up your browser developer tools and go to the Network tab, then load a page. Select the "Type" column, and then you can examine those with a Type of `script`. For example, on Stack Overflow, you'll see something like:

[image]

As you can see, Stack Exchange loads jQuery, a script named `stub.en.js`, a script named `clc.min.js`, and a few more. To see what those scripts contain, either click on them in the Network tab, or right-click and select "Open in new tab" to view it as a standalone tab.

But professional sites often minify their Javascript, and complicated minified Javascript is very difficult to read. Better to read *source* code whenever possible, not *distribution* code, to save yourself a headache.

Comment: Also all the source code is available in the "sources" tab.